# how can I write this code of c# to be in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

how can I write the following code written in c# to vb.net. 
I am trying to write a finger print program but I got stuck to this point
what is the right way to do it?

```
 public bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)
            {
                if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
                {
                    //65535, 32767
                    if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))
                    {
                        // [ Register your events here ]
                        // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a complete list of events
                        objCZKEM.OnConnected += ObjCZKEM_OnConnected;
                        objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += objCZKEM_OnDisConnected;
                        objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger;
                        objCZKEM.OnFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnFinger;
                        objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
////////////////////////////////////////////
```

> and here is the code I want to try to convert to:

```
<!-- language: vb.net -->

Public Function Connect_Net(ByVal IPAdd As String, ByVal Port As Integer) As Boolean
                If objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port) Then

                    If objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767) Then
                        objCZKEM.OnConnected += AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnConnected
                        objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += AddressOf objCZKEM_OnDisConnected
                        objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger
                        objCZKEM.OnFinger += AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnFinger
                        objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += New _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(AddressOf zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx)
                    End If

                    Return True
                End If

                Return False
            End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''

But:
I get this error:

> Error 4   Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Object' and
>   'Void'.   C:\Users\PC50\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Ref_Con\Ref_Con\Utilities\ZkemClient.vb

Comment: did you try http://converter.telerik.com/  or https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ ?

Comment: Um, the code you posted is VB.NET. Are you actually saying that you want the C# equivalent, because you actually said the opposite? Regardless, SO is not a code-writing service. You need to do what you can and then you can post here if you encounter a specific issue, i.e. the specific code translation that you write doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry!
I pasted the code that I was trying to modify 
I will edit the post

Comment: Yes, I did, but I am getting an error because it is not converted correctly.

Comment: jmcilhinney 
I am trying by best by I got stuck to this point 
Please, can you help me with this point

Comment: Post (edit your question) your conversion attempts and the error you are getting.

Comment: In C# we add event handlers like: `eventRaisingThing.EventName += MethodNameThatHandlesEvent;`. In VB we add event handlers like `AddHandler eventRaisingThing.EventName, AddressOf MethodNameThatHandlesEvent`. Your syntax mixes the two because of those stray `+=` making VB thing youre trying to perform maths addition like 2+2. Fix it to be VB style. If this question ever gets reopened I'll put this as an answer

Comment: e.g. `AddHandler objCZKEM.OnConnected, AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnConnected`, not `objCZKEM.OnConnected += AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnConnected`

Comment: If you want to get reopen votes, you'll need to change it so it doesnt say "stuck converting this c# to VB please write it for me" - make it like "I'm converting some C# which looks like [paste c#] to VB and I have written [paste your VB} and I'm getting an error that says [ paste the error] - what does the error mean? How do I fix it?". Essentially your question IS only about a single thing - how to programatically add an event handler in VB, its just that the way you wrote the question, it leads with "please do my work for me" and it's very confused (you say "here is c#" and then paste VB)

Comment: this is what I need
In vb: AddHandler eventRaisingThing.EventName, AddressOf MethodNameThatHandlesEvent

ex: AddHandler objCZKEM.OnConnected, AddressOf ObjCZKEM_OnConnected